# Use database in Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, sql, database, swift, sqlite

I did some search about using database in swift, I found many subject with SQLLite but they use librairies from GitHub and other, but I want to know if they're something built-in on iOS Swift, because I don't want to use librairies.

Comment: You can use [core data](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) provided by ios SDK

Comment: @RatulSharker I'm gonna do search I think it's new on Swift2 no ?

Comment: @Ben it has been there for very long time already...but it need to write pretty a lot of extra code, i recomend Realm, its fast and its easy

Comment: Actually I used core data in swift 2.0 project but written in objective-c and bridged it to swift.Because swift can't work well with C APIs.

Comment: Just to be clear, SQLite is **completely built-in** to iOS.  Easy tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift  Also, there is a very popular wrapper for SQLite: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Coredata? I haven't tried swift yet, but I'm sure it will be similar to using it with Objective-C.

Comment: Oh I haven't found about this, I learned that it's new on Swift2 I'm gonna look it

Comment: It's not new per se, but it is a framework provided by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

There are database available for iOS like CoreData, RealM, SQLite, etc.

CoreData is a ObjectGraph DataStore, based on SQLite,

Coredata is easy to learn, understand and implement as compared to SQLite syntax.

Use CoreData. Follow this awesome tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I've coredata book link - this book will have swift/Objective-C both, You can refer it and integrate on your project. I've read this book and learned from it thoroughly, in this you will also find how to add coredata in existing project. I hope this will help you through. [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ali36pova4xeyeh/IOS%20Persistance%20service.pdf?dl=0)